# Oracle Update Statement Using a Join

Tags: oracle, join, sql-update

I need some help with this query. It works fine in SSMS, but will not work in Oracle. How can I rewrite this so it will work in Oracle? I really appreciate the help.

```
UPDATE reservation_Daily_elements e
SET e.MARKET_CODE = 'PHEE', 
    e.ORIGIN_OF_BOOKING = 'DESKTOP'
FROM reservation_Daily_elements e
LEFT JOIN reservation_daily_element_name dn
          ON e.resv_daily_el_seq = dn.resv_daily_el_seq
WHERE dn.RESV_NAME_ID IN ('3747957');
Commit;
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[oracle]+update+join

Comment: "but will not work in Oracle." What does that mean?

Comment: T-SQL vs PL-SQL

Answer (score 0):

How about `MERGE`?

```
merge into reservation_daily_elements e
using (select dn.resv_daily_el_seq
       from reservatioin_daily_element_name dn
       where dn.resv_name_id = '3747957'
      ) x
on (e.resv_daily_el_seq = x.resv_daily_el_seq)
when matched then update set
  e.market_code = 'PHEE',
  e.origin_of_booking = 'DESKTOP';
```

If it has to be `UPDATE`, then

```
update reservation_daily_elements e set
  e.market_code = 'PHEE',
  e.origin_of_booking = 'DESKTOP'
where exists (select null
              from reservation_daily_element_name dn
              where dn.resv_daily_el_seq = e.resv_daily_el_seq
                and dn.resv_name = '3747957'
             );
```

Comment: That's perfect!! Thank you so much Littlefoot!! I swear I tried writing the UPDATE statement like you did and it didn't work.  However, your code worked beautifully!!

Answer (score 0):

Btw, oracle supports updatable inline views, so you can use simple `update (Select... From t1 join t2 on...) set...` .

Also as I see your 'left join' is really 'inner join' because of the predicates in where clause.